# Does ADP + P => ATP produce water?

Tags: biochemistry

ADP + P has one oxygen and two hydrogen more atoms than ATP. Are these atoms released as water in the reaction ADP + P => ATP? To balance the equation, would ADP + P => ATP + H2O be more correct?

Comment: Yes. H2O is produced in the reaction ADP + P -->  ATP.  But we usually used not to mention it, because the organic part of the reaction is more important

Comment: It is analogical as we often implicitly include water into the equilibrium constant. Consider the above rather as the reaction schema than reaction enumeration.